# How to draw custom, complicated ui element

Tags: python, scripting, interface, opengl

Is it possible to add custom drawn elements to UI? e.g. access OpenGL and draw shapes from code, create some "canvas" in UI and draw on it.

e.g. I'd like to create a complicated interface, something that cannot be done with standard blender ui elements, like:

[image: Complicated rigging ui]
or
[image: Timeline]
Or some kind of a preview for math functions, particular list items, there  are many possible use cases.
Maya/Max UI is made in Qt, so they are very flexible, but I understand what problems does this cause and I am not criticizing a way that Blender UI works. I'm just looking for some flexibility.

I do know about one solution:
[Creating UI as an element of the scene, made from "real" objects](https://www.blendernation.com/2017/11/09/rigui-add-creates-configurable-interface-rigs/)
I know that this is a popular solution for rigs, you've got some controls created with e.g. splines. And it works for rigs well, but what if you've got many objects in the scene and would like to have a single place for controlling them all? What if you'd like to create UI for browsing a database, disk files, or you'd like to create some lists with elements, with scrolling, or combo box? So this is not a solution for me. Also, that's a little bit hacky

Can [bgl module](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_72_1/bgl.html) be used for this or does it only affect a viewport area? Dos anyone have some example of it?

Regards